# How do I display all the items from a javascript list under each other in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I'm working on a dummy operating-system in HTML. In this operating system there is a program called the Application Manager. A part of that program is to display a list of all the running applications. Here is the code:

```javascript
var x = activeApps
document.getElementById('openAppsList').innerHTML = x
```

The problem is, when I do this, the text that shows up on screen is this:

[image: !Image of app names concatenated instead of on newlines]

Is there any way that I can show the items under each other, like this:

```
AppManager
Downloads
myPictures
```

I'm using vanilla JavaScript on a local Apache Server.

Comment: Can you include your css, and content of `activeApps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
x = 'AppManager,Downloads,myPictures'
document.getElementById('openAppsList').innerHTML = x.replace(/\,/g, '<br/>');
```

```html
<html>
<body><div id="openAppsList"></div>
</body>
</html>
```